# He was arrested ________ a charge of murder

Tags: prepositions

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission test 2008-09*

Q) He was arrested ________ a charge of murder.

(a) on

(b) for

(c) with

(d) about

Question bank says that the answer is (b). I think that "arrested on charges of..." is a common phrase. That's why I think that (a) is correct. Am I right?

**Edit:**

I request answers/comments that reflect common practices of American and British English.

Comment: You recently edited a question to add this clarification: *I request answers/comments that reflect common practices of American and British English.* I recommend adding it to every question about this lousy test.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney Only someone familiar with English as used natively in Bangladesh would be able to say if the test is lousy.

Comment: I suspect that the test is fine, but the answer bank is lousy.  Such tests are intended to assess standard English for international communication, and not the local dialect.  So if the answers are only correct when interpreted in the local dialect, then the test is not doing what it claims to do - and is lousy.  But I don't think the test **is** lousy.  I think the test questions have been retyped for the answerbank and a non-native speaker (and not the writer of the test) has provided solutions.  Some of these solutions are wrong.@gotube

Comment: @JamesK Yes. The Question bank has been provided by a third party not affiliated with the University.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your belief is correct. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arrested+on+a+charge%2Carrested+for+a+charge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carrested%20on%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrested%20for%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Carrested%20on%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrested%20for%20a%20charge%3B%2Cc0) shows that instances of **arrested for a charge** are vanishingly small, many fractions of a percent less common than **arrested on a charge**.

One is **arrested *on a charge* of murder.**

One is ***charged with* murder.**

One is **arrested *for the crime* of murder** — or, more simply, **arrested *for murder***.

Admittedly, I normally encounter such phrases in fiction. It's entirely possible that real law enforcement agents use them differently.